# Starting Order by a value, And if the value isn't exist get others

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

for this database

```
[     title    -    content    -     class     ]
[      PHP     -     lOREM     -       a       ]
[      CSS     -     Lorem     -       b       ]
[      PDO     -     lOREM     -       c       ]
[      PHP     -     Lorem     -       d       ]
```

I want to start the order by class = a, But if this row with this class doesn't exist, it shows the next in order directly, I use this query

```
SELECT title, content FROM posts WHERE title = :title ORDER BY class = 'a' DESC LIMIT 1
```

When the row of class a doesn't exist, nothing appears. How can i solve this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What is `id`?  Provide desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fixed it a little, I want it to go to class d if class a doesn't exist

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with prioritization:

```
SELECT p.title, p.content
FROM posts p
WHERE p.title = :title
ORDER BY (CASE class WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 WHEN 'c' THEN 3 WHEN 'd' THEN 4 END)
LIMIT 1;
```

Or more simply:

```
ORDER BY field(class, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Of course, in your case, the classes are alphabetical, so you could just do:

```
ORDER BY class ASC
```

EDIT:

If you want to put one class before the others:

```
ORDER BY (class = 'A') DESC, class
```

Comment: But in my case, I have like a 200 type of classes, Isn't it possible to start with `A` then by the natural order?

Comment: @CaliburVictorious . . . Look at the last suggestion.  If alphabetic ordering works, then just use `ORDER BY class`.

Comment: But i want for example to start with the letter S, then if S doesn't exist, To go to the usual order, I can use PHP to do this, But is that possible using SQL only?

Answer (score 0):

Your fault is using quotes `"` instead of apostrophes `'` for your text literal, plus it's simpler to reverse condition (true sorts after false).

Try this:

```
SELECT title, content
FROM posts
WHERE title = :title
ORDER BY class != 'a', class -- instead of "a"
LIMIT 1
```